# Estimating costs with extreme values

Tags: estimation, model, median, extreme-value, weighted-mean

I am trying to estimate health care costs and I was wondering what the standard practice is for extreme values?

By extreme values I mean I have a large portion of my costs being zero and a small portion of my costs exceeding $\$100,000$. In this case is it better to use a mean the median? And what is the justification?

Or are their conventions for cost estimates of health care of maybe looking in an interval?

Any help, comments or references would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer to your question depends on the reason you are doing the research.
(1) If you want to make statements about the total (or mean) cost, then you must use the mean of all your data.  Only if you think the outliers will never reoccur would omitting the outliers make sense.
(2) If you want to describe the vast majority of your health care users, then a median or a trimmed mean would make sense.